# Picking only valid image files from Gallery(SD card) but not the fake ones(the ones with an image extension but not actually an image file)

Tags: java, android, image, mime-types

I pick up an image successfully from sd card by sending an intent with `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)` and accordingly handling the response on `onActivityResult`.

Now suppose someone changed the extension of (say) a `.txt` file to `.jpg`.And the user not knowingly when try to pick that file, the app crashes by throwing `java.lang.RuntimeException` and `java.lang.NullPointerException`.Thus i used `MimeUtil` (`mime-util-2.1.3.jar`) to get the mimetype of the file, something like this

```
public static String findMimeTypeOfFile(String originalPath)
{
    MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.MagicMimeMimeDetector");
    MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.ExtensionMimeDetector");
    MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.OpendesktopMimeDetector");
    Collection<?> mimeTypes = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(originalPath);

    if (mimeTypes.isEmpty())
    {
       return "text/plain";
    } else
    {
        Iterator<?> iterator = mimeTypes.iterator();
        MimeType mimeType = (MimeType) iterator.next();
        String mimetype = mimeType.getMediaType() + "/" + mimeType.getSubType();
        return mimetype;
    }
}
```

And for checking an valid image used

```
if(findMimeTypeOfFile(path).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg") || findMimeTypeOfFile(path).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("image/pjpeg") || findMimeTypeOfFile(path).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("image/png") || findMimeTypeOfFile(path).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("image/gif") || findMimeTypeOfFile(path).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("image/bmp")){

//valid image

}
else{

 //invalid image

}
```

Now this worked fine for valid images but again didn't work for fake ones.The `if()` block was executed even if i load a `.txt` file having `.jpg` extension.

**Question**

1.What changes do i need to make to the `findMimeTypeOfFile` method?Isn't it possible to solve this issue using `MimeUtil` only?

2.I see whatsapp shows an `AlertDialog` when a fake image like this is loaded, saying "invalid image".Do you know how whatsapp deals with this issue?

Comment: You could try loading the image inside a try/catch, and show the alert message when it fails.

Comment: @JWiley : Yeah did that and obviously that worked as expected.And that satisfies my purpose too.However just to be more neat and accurate, i wanted to execute that `else` block of code instead of `if()` when a fake image is picked.

Comment: You could put whatever you're doing in the `else{ //invalid image}` in the `finally` block in your try/catch

Answer (score 0):

I simply loaded the image inside a `try catch block`.When an exception is raised showed an `AlertDialog` saying "Invalid image". I know it sounds silly as an answer, but i hope someone gets valuable info about the use of `MimeUtil` from this post.